# ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: could not parse service account URL

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I want to use a custom Service Account to build my docker container with Cloud Build. Using `gcloud iam service-accounts list` and `gcloud config list` I have confirmed that the service account is in the project environment and I used `gcloud services list --enabled` to check that `cloudbuild.googleapis.com` is enabled. I get the error: `ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) INVALID_ARGUMENT: could not parse service account URL`. I tried all of the available service accounts and I tried with and without the prefix path. What is the correct URL or config after steps to get the service account working?

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/my-project-id/my-app']
images: ['gcr.io/my-project-id/my-app']
serviceAccount: 'projects/my-project-id/serviceAccount/my-sa@my-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
options:
  logging: CLOUD_LOGGING_ONLY
```

Comment: `projects/{project-id}/serviceAccounts/{service-account-email}` ... `serviceAccounts` plural.

Comment: Life saver, please post as answer.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build config for [serviceAccount](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#serviceaccount) references [this](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/configure-user-specified-service-accounts#running_builds_from_the_command_line) page and there's an example that shows the structure:

```
projects/{project-id}/serviceAccounts/{service-account-email}
```

So, it follows Google's API convention of a plural noun (i.e. `serviceAccounts`) followed by the unique identifier.

Another way to confirm this is via [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer) for [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest).

The service's [Build](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build) resource defines [serviceAccount](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#Build.FIELDS.service_account) too.